# Obter dados de cada linha de uma coluna em C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

É o seguinte, eu tenho uma `DataGridView` com várias colunas. Em cada linha dessa `DataGridView` será apresentado o caminho de instalação de um programa. Com esse valor apresentado, eu gostaria de utiliza-lo para obter o tamanho dessa pasta e colocá-lo numa coluna nova.

Eu tenho um método para calcular o tamanho de uma string:

```
private static long ObterTamanhoDiretorio(string tamanhoDir)
{
    DirectoryInfo dire = new DirectoryInfo(tamanhoDir.ToString());
    return dire.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Sum(fi => fi.Length);
}
```

Não sei se é algo deste género que eu tenho que utilizar.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dataGridView1.Rows)
{

}
```

O que eu gostava de saber é como fazer para obter esse valor vendo em cada linha.
Se tiverem alguma ideia agradeço.

Comment: Se você já tiver os caminhos no `DataSource` antes de setar no `DataGridView`, você pode fazer um `foreach` direto na sua fonte de dados, que deve ser um `List` ou um `DataTable`. Você também pode usar o evento `RowDataBound` do `DataGridView`, que irá ler cada linha sendo renderizada no grid, então podes pegar o valor da coluna e passar para o seu método para calcular o tamanho.

Comment: Como você preenche o DataGridView?

Answer (score 2):

Caso você deseje executar essa ação ao carregar os dados pode utilizar o evento
'OnRowDataBound':

```
  gdvView.DataSource = Lista;
  gdvView.DataBind();


protected void GdvViewOnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "dados coluna 1";
            e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "dados coluna 2";
        }
    }
```

Se necessitar fazer a mudança após a Grid está preenchida, pode ser usada o for ou foreach.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < gdvView.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            gdvView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text = "novos dados";
        }
```

Ou

```
 foreach (var row in gdvView.Rows)
        {
            ((gdvView)row).Cells[0].Text = "testeeeee";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Usando o exemplo do @Cleidson_eng, fiz em uma aplicação minha para recuperar os valores e ir somando e no final apresentar o valor final. Caso te ajude de alguma forma, segue:

```
protected void gvInscricoesCurso_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
      int total = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < gvInscricoesCurso.Rows.Count; i++)
      {
        total += Convert.ToInt32(gvInscricoesCurso.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text);
        spanTotalInscritosGeral.InnerText = total.ToString();
        divTotalGeral.Visible = true;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Caso tenho solucionado o seu problema, marcar como resposta.